# Ansible ec2 termination task failing

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ansible

I have the following instance creation task in Ansible:

```
- name: Provisioning Spot instaces
  ec2:
    assign_public_ip: no
    spot_price: "{{ ondemand4_price }}"
    spot_wait_timeout: 300
    assign_public_ip: no
    aws_access_key: "{{ assumed_role.sts_creds.access_key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ assumed_role.sts_creds.secret_key }}"
    security_token: "{{ assumed_role.sts_creds.session_token }}"
    region: "{{ aws_region }}"
    image: "{{ image_instance }}"
    instance_type: "{{ large_instance }}"
    key_name: "{{ ssh_keyname }}"
    count: "{{ ninstances }}"
    state: present
    group_id: "{{ cypher_priv_sg }}"
    vpc_subnet_id: "{{ private_subnet_id }}"
    instance_profile_name: 'Cypher-Ansible'
    wait: true
    instance_tags:
      Name: Cypher-Worker
    #delete_on_termination: yes
  register: ec2
  ignore_errors: True
```

And then the termination task is:

```
- name: Terminate instances that were previously launched
  connection: local
  become: false
  ec2:
    state: 'absent'
    instance_ids: '{{ ec2.instance_ids }}'
    region: '{{ aws_region }}'
  register: TerminateWorker
  ignore_errors: True
```

But, instead of terminating my Worker instances, it throws an error which says:

```
TASK [Terminate instances that were previously launched] ***********************
task path: /path/to/file/Ansible/provision.yml:373
fatal: [x.y.a.202]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ec2' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/path/to/file/Ansible/provision.yml': line 373, column 7, but maybe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: Terminate instances that were previously launched\n      ^ here\n\nexception type: <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleUndefinedVariable'>\nexception: 'ec2' is undefined"
}
```

What might be the issue here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your task looks fine on first look. But why do you use the "connection" and "become" flags on termination? Just asking because you don't use them in the provisioning task.

**EDIT2:** Are your provisioning- and termination-tasks in the same play? If yes you can access the registered "ec2" variable like this:

```
- name: Terminate instances that were previously launched
  ec2:
    state: 'absent'
    instance_ids: '{{ item.instance_id }}'
    region: "{{ aws_region }}"
    wait: yes
    wait_timeout: 500
  with_items: "{{ ec2.instances }}"
```

If your termination task is in another play of the same playbook run you have to use the *set_fact* task to make it accessible for other plays.

If your termination task will be executed in an entirely different playbook run you can find out your instance ids with *ec2_instance_facts* like this:

```
- name: get ec2 instance id by its name tag
  ec2_instance_facts:
    filters:
      "tag:ec2_instance_name": "{{ ecs_instance_name }}"
      instance-state-name: running
  register: instances
```

With this method you have to set the above mentioned tag via the provisioning task.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. btw, not the instance id's can be accessed by `item.id` instead of `item.instance_id`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the ec2 var to ise in that task.
You can add:
`with_items: {{ ec2 }}`
At the end of your termination task and it'll pick this up from the registrated var in the above task.

Comment: Not working. Possible to give add a code example please?